# A putative memory leak in ChoosePixelFormat

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, memory-leaks

The following problem was encountered when testing a C++ Windows Application which uses OpenGL for drawing. For the test, I used the GlowCode 9.1 profiler.

After end of the application, it is indicated that the method **GDI32!ChoosePixelFormat** has leaked quite a lot of memory, over 6 MB.

The application closes all the resources according to openGL specifications, namely invoking:

```
wglMakeCurrent(iMainHDC, NULL);
wglDeleteContext(iMainHRC);
wglMakeCurrent(iHSHDC, NULL);
wglDeleteContext(iHSHRC);   
DeleteGDI(iHSGDIBackBufferBitmap, iHSGDIBackBufferDC);
DestroyWindow(iHSWindowHandle);
DeleteGDI(iMainGDIBackBufferBitmap, iMainGDIBackBufferDC);
DestroyWindow(iMainWindowHandle);
```

so it shouldn't be the case of forgetting to destroy the resources.

Do I need to run some other deallocation procedures in order to get rid of this memory leak?

My aim is to have the application leak 0 bytes upon exit. Can this be done at all? Or do Windows graphics libraries keep some data allocated as singletons etc.?

Could it be just a problem with the local graphics driver?

Comment: Can you provide a complete minimal example that produces the memory leak?

Comment: ChoosePixelFormat shouldn't to any allocations to be freed later at all. Something else may be leaking memory and that getting wrongly attributed to ChoosePixelFormat. Also note that those `wglMakeCurrent` calls are superfluous. `wglMakeCurrent` doesn't bind a OpenGL rendering context to a DC, `wglMakeCurrent` binds a pair consisting of a DC and a RC to the current thread. Just calling `wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL)` once suffices. But you have to call it in *all* of the threads that made use of OpenGL.

Comment: Is it possible that whatever tool you're using to detect these memory leaks is reacting to the driver setting aside storage for your backbuffer? This is about the only thing I can think of that happens when you select a pixel format that has anything to do with memory. `ReleaseDC (...)` ought to clean that up, but I don't think it'll work when you have the HDC bound to the current calling thread. I would try datenwolf's suggestion, as that may resolve this issue.

Comment: I have further experimented with this issue, using GDIView. Several DCs, bitmaps, fonts and brushes survive the destruction of all the windows of the app. Three of those DCs are allocated in ChoosePixelFormat. It is possibly due to the GDI subsystem cache, or a problem with the Nvidia driver. I am still exploring other options.

Comment: Also, some of the leaking resources (5 of 13) are associated with the console window for text output which opens next to the graphic windows. I am not sure what to do with it.